# removing from a linked list in C based off of the index your at

Tags: c, indexing, linked-list

So far I have managed to delete everything from the ith index but I need to be able to connect the node from before the ith to the node after the ith index this is what I have so far.

```
LinklistNode* remove_node(LinklistNode* list_head, int index){
if(list_head != NULL){
    LinklistNode* temp;
    if(list_head-> next ==NULL){
        temp = list_head;
        list_head = NULL;
    }
    else{
        LinklistNode* list_pointer = list_head;
        LinklistNode* next_list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
        while(next_list_pointer->next != NULL && index > 0){
            index--;
            list_pointer = next_list_pointer;
            next_list_pointer = next_list_pointer->next;
        }
        temp = next_list_pointer;
        list_pointer->next = NULL;
    }
    free(temp);
   }
   return list_head;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I delete the Ith position of linked list @this

Comment: That is too vague. What specific problems are you having, what have you tried so far to solve the problem, where are you stuck??

Comment: @this sorry for not give detail I guess my problem is happening when Im removing the index right now I have code similar to what rohit89 posted but   it is removing one index too far and before that my problem was that I was unable to connect the Ith-1 index to the Ith+1 index without destroying the rest of the list.hope this clears stuff up let me know if you have any more questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link the nodes before and after the index, point `list_pointer->next` to  `next_list_pointer->next`

```
while(next_list_pointer->next != NULL){
        index--;
        if (index == 0) break;
        list_pointer = next_list_pointer;
        next_list_pointer = next_list_pointer->next;
}
temp = next_list_pointer;
list_pointer->next = temp->next;
```

Comment: It looks like when I do this that the node being removed is off by 1 index as in it is removing the 9th not the 8th (that was just a test I tried) @rothit89

Comment: What if the input index is 0? In that case head needs to be changed to point to the second node.

Comment: @rcgldr thanks for pointing that out I just added a simple if statement and fixed that problem I probably wouldn't have noticed if you never pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect the node before the ith element use your list_pointer. Have something like 
...

```
while(next_list_pointer != NULL || index != 0){
    list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    next_list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
}

if(next_list_pointer == NULL){
   printf("Invalid index given. Nothing deleted.\n");
   //Do not delete otherwise an error will be given
   return list_head;
} else {
   //Valid index was given 
   list_pointer->next = next_list_pointer->next;
   free(next_list_pointer);
   return list_head;
}
```

...
This should pretty much cover the deletion portion just be sure to include your base cases.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method using pointer to pointer to node:

```
LinklistNode* remove_node(LinklistNode* list_head, int index)
{
LinklistNode **ppNode = &list_head;
    if(list_head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    while(index--){
        ppNode = &((*ppNode)->next);
        if(*ppNode == NULL)             /* if index not in list */
            return list_head;           /*   just return */
    }
    *ppNode = (*ppNode)->next;          /* delete node */
    return list_head;
}
```